# redirect to another page based on user type

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('awnb') or die(mysql_erroe());
        $Email=$_GET['LoginEmail'];
        $password=$_GET['LoginPassword'];
        if($Email!=""&&$password!="") {
            $query=mysql_query("select * from users where Email='".$Email."' and Password='".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());
            $res=mysql_fetch_row($query);
            if($res) {
                $userType = $res['Type'];
                if($userType == 'user') {
                    $_SESSION['Email']=$Email;
                    header("location:profileuser.php");
                    exit;
                } else if($userType == 'sec') {
                    $_SESSION['Email']=$Email;
                    header("location:profile.php");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                echo "
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Username or Password is incorrect');
                </script>";
                header("location:index.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Enter both Username and Passowrd');
            </script>";
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

- In this code Type is an attribute in table which tells about the type of user,there are two types of users called as user or sec. if type is user it should redirect to profileuser.php otherwise to profile.php but i am unable to do redirect the pages based on user type.

Comment: What is the error you getting  while you try to redirect ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Type in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_phpform.php on line 16

Comment: @Harindranath: Then there's no `Type` column in the result from the database.

Comment: You don't have a column Type in your mysql response.

Comment: What happens if you try to echo the `$res['Type']` ? I guess there is not any coloumn named `Type` in your table

Comment: no, there is a Type column in table

Comment: Do a `print_r($res)` to show the structure of the array. It may be that it is `$res[0]['Type']` ... Also, it is case sensitive, so `Type` is not the same as `type`

Comment: Array ( [0] => achyuth42@gmail.com [1] => Achyuth [2] => BL.EN.U4CSE12028 [3] => achyuth [4] => 8123951947 [5] => cse [6] => 6 [7] => user )             if i do   print_r($res)   i am getting the above thing, in that [7] => user , user is in Type column @Stretch

Comment: Yeah, so you'd reference to it as `$res[7]` ... Or, research how you would get the column names as the key (Try looking for mysql fetch associations). I use mysql PDO to do queries (Which I would recommend by the way) and you would get the coumn names by doing `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, you are fetching a row that has a [numeric index](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated
>   with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array.
>   Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

If you want to get a associative array, you need [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

That said, there is so much wrong with your code that you should probably start over:

- The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated;
- You have an [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) problem;
- You are storing a plain-text password;
- You are echoing output before a `header` redirect;
- You use GET instead of POST to send sensitive login data.

You can find a lot of information about each point here on SO so I am not going to repeat it, but like I said, you should probably just start over.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the edit. I actually hesitated if I should answer at all as it was all a bit too much for a Sunday afternoon :-)

Comment: @jeroen grazie mille :-)